# Do we pay cheaper fees for less security in P2TR rather than P2PKH?

Tags: ecdsa, schnorr-signatures, p2pkh, p2tr, ripemd160

Answer quote:

> [P2TR now is a spiritual successor of P2PK: it locks funds directly to a key and only requires a signature to spend the funds.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/116689/126793)

If P2TR UTXOs are guarded by [Schnorr signatures](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki) and P2PKH ones are guarded by ECDSA [plus a later RIPEMD160 stage](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address#Address_map), my question is: do we pay cheaper fees for less security in P2TR rather than using P2PKH, even though using P2TR is obviously *currently* reasonable (specially for *short lived* UTXOs)?

... abstracting from the rest of advantages of taproot, like improved privacy for everyone...

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/93047/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91049/5406

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the potential attacks against ECDSA that would be possible if we used raw public keys as addresses?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95123/what-are-the-potential-attacks-against-ecdsa-that-would-be-possible-if-we-used-r)

Comment: thankyoubothverymurch

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't less (weaker) cryptographic security in P2TR- than P2PKH-type of UTXO (or locking script). As a matter of fact, there are improvements and (useless) complexity removed (to some extent). There is a lot of information about it in the Bitcoin Explained podcast (e.g. episode 2) by Sjors Provoost and Aaron van Wirdum.

Comment: care to link it please?

Comment: I believe Greg is referring to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3tXgN7oxaY